# Getting a 404 Not Found CF Error API

Tags: web-services, api, coldfusion

I am trying to connect to an external web service to access their database for certain operations. I have the following code, but when I run, it gives a

"404 Not Found" CFE.

```
<cfscript>
httpService = new http();
httpService.setMethod("Post");
httpService.setThrowOnError(true);
httpService.setTimeOut(30);
httpService.setURL("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.svc");//THEIR http
httpService.setusername("MY USERNAME I HAVE BEEN GIVEN TO ACCESS THEIR web");
httpService.setPassword("THE PASSWORD THEY ASSIGNED ME");   
httpService.addParam(type="body", name="Content-Type", value="text/plain");

result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
</cfscript>
```

Can anyone help?

I have also tried setting userName and password like this. But I don't know if that's even the issue.

```
httpService.addParam(type="formfield", name="userName", value="MY USERNAME");
```

When I change

```
 httpService.setURL("httpxxxxxxxxx.svc");
```

to

```
 httpService.setURL("httpxxxxxxxxx.svc/basicHttp");
```

it gives "415 Unsupported Media Type" instead. Haven't found a real source that helps me with this issue. These are the URL I am being given by the external source.

thanks.

Comment: does CF have issues connecting to a .svc?? would that be an issue?

Comment: CF won't care what the extension on the remote URL is. Your problem is likely elsewhere

Comment: Have you changed the param type=body to type=header? The unsupported media type error may be related to the fact that the content-type header in your request will not be set.

Comment: barnyr - yes I changed that to header as you stated...but doesn't help. The only thing that makes it seem as if its connecting is changing the SetMethod("Post") to "Get". But when I want to connect to a database in my cfquery datasource="", it does not pick up the datasource, so I'm assuming it's not connected properly.

Comment: I'm not sure that getprefix() is going to do anything for you. The prefix only really matters when calling the tag based version of cfhttp. Also, I'm not sure how queries relate to the HTP call? Have you tried WriteDump(httpService.send()) instead of your result=.... code.  that should show what the server is sending back, along with error codes etc..

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with the line below:

```
httpService.addParam(type="body", name="Content-Type", value="text/plain");
```

You probably want the type to be "header" as per [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html). I'm not sure if that's necessarily going to stop a 404 error (that'll depend on the external web service).

If that doesn't fix it, what I'd do next is :

- Install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)
- Start Fiddler
- add  httpService.setProxyServer("127.0.0.1") httpService.setProxyPort("8888") to your code
- retry the ColdFusion page. The requests should now appear in Fiddler.

You can now inspect the request and response, which may give you clues as to what's not working. You can also save out the request as a .SAZ file from fiddler and send to the developer of the service and they can look at it and may be able to give you feedback.

Comment: When I remove the setThrowOnError it works, but I'm not sure why that would have anything to do with it. I wish I could install Fiddler, but unfortunately, this is a company machine and I can't install apps that are not approved:(

Comment: Boo to software lockdown! Seriously, I'd put the request in to get Fiddler onto your approved list. It may not help you this time, but it will in the future.